# atom\xml python feedparser <content> enclosing access

Tags: python, xml, feedparser

How to access 'content' enclosing with feedparser?

```
<content type="application/xml">
<m:properties xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">
<d:Ref_Key>3a496b6e</d:Ref_Key
</m:properties>
</content>
```

Code to access 'content'

```
d = feedparser.parse("http://localhos/odata/standard.odata/Document_Order")
d.entries[0].content[0]
```

returns something like

```
{'base': u'http://localhos/odata/standard.odata/Document_Order', 'type': u'application/xml', 'value': u'', 'language': None}
```

Then how to get 'm:properties' and 'd:Ref_Key' ?

Comment: What you have there is not proper XML

Comment: What do `dir(d.entries)` and `d.entries.__dict__` give you?

Comment: >>dir(d.entries)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']

Comment: Something same for d.entries[0]

Comment: Yes elements like <d:Ref_Key> are not XML. It would be sine to have an access to body of <content> and then parse it on own

Answer (score 0):

It seems feedparser cant pars not XML tags, advice to use xml.etree.ElementTree

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree

url = http://localhost/standard.odata/Document_Visit

req = requests.get(self.url, auth=(self.login, self.password))
root = etree.fromstring(req.text.encode('utf-8'))
entrys = root.findall('{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry')
properties = content.findall('{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata}properties')
prop_dict = dict()
for prop in properties[0]:
   pritn prop
```